403 ERROR (FORBIDDEN) - When Publishing a .NET Core Web Application in HostGator
I created an ASP .NET Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller) in Visual Studio 2022.
I concluded the development and now i want to publish it in the web using HostGator.
I uploaded all the project files in HostGator Platform but i am getting the 403 ERROR - FORBIDDEN.
When exporting the project files to a folder i got the following output:
Files generated after publishing the project in Visual Studio
Could you please help me to understand why i am getting this 403 ERROR - FORBIDDEN ?
This is the current project structure:

You have in your controller [Authorize] and then are not allowing the user authorization to the route.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute.  You need to add a Role to the Route.

Are you getting this error for all the pages or any particular page? Was the deployment successful? However, in general The 403 Forbidden error typically indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it. The web server does not have permission to access the files or directories. Ensure that the correct permissions are set for your application's files and directories. Also, make sure that the web.config file is correctly configured and present in the root directory of your application. This file is crucial for configuring the application settings and permissions.

Actually this is the first project i am publishing in the web, i could develop and run it successfully in my browser when using http://localhost:5198 url.
My routes seems to be ok because this root url is point to my Home/Index controller.
After publishing it i can access the text only files in the browser like "mysite.com/appsettings.json" but the html is not renderized

Please make sure you have setup your default page correctly. Forbidden error message usually happened because you haven't setup your own default page. Please also read this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-solve-error-403-forbidden-error-in-asp-net/.
